# How to upgrade to java 1.6 from java 1.5 in Oracle Application Server

Tags: oracle, application-server, oas, oracle-application-server

Interested in upgrading JAVA VERSION from JAVA 1.5 to JAVA 1.6

```
[oracle@server301 /]$ java -version
java version "1.5.0_12"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_12-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.5.0_12-b04, mixed mode)
```

also interested in knowing Oracle Application Server VERSION (from command line )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you need to install java 1.6

If you want to change it for the whole OAS then alias `java` to your new java directory (1.6).
If you want to change it for a specific `OC4J`, then:

1. Open opmn/conf/opmn.xml
2. find the element  which represend your OC4J
3. update the value in the element: `process-type/module-data/category/data` where id="java-bin", to your new java path
4. restart OAS